# Runner Misses Third Base

Tags: baseball

What is the correct call when a runner misses third base; touches the plate and then goes back to third and is called out trying to score?

Comment: The "called out trying to score" part is very non-specific.  Was the runner tagged at some point?  Was there an appeal?  Did the runner make it back to third and then try to score again?  Is this an MLB question or some other league?

Comment: The runner was tagged out at the plate trying to score again after going back to touch third.  This happened in a Little League game.

Comment: Does this mean the runner touched home plate, and then 3rd base, and then got tagged out?

Answer (score 1):

If the runner missed third base, then they are not entitled to score and are not in a safe position until and unless they return to third.  (Sounds like this was happening).

If the runner is tagged with the ball before returning to third base, it's an out.

Touching or not touching home plate doesn't matter much here.  The runner shouldn't be automatically out for doing so.  Although as a little league game, there may be some additional rules that differ from mlb.

Comment: I agree thanks.  There doesn't seem to be any direct wording in the rules either little league or MLB.  The runner was called out by me as plate umpire trying to score after returning to third and then trying to go back to home.